# Why can't I remove my custom App from MS Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am using Microsoft Teams Version 1.4.00.34557. It was last updated on 13/01/2022.
I used to be able to upload and delete custom Apps using the Teams desktop app.

I had a button in the UI to delete my custom app until the latest update.

I no longer have a way in the UI to delete the custom app.
The app appears in the "Built for your org" list of apps, and I can "Add to a team" or "Add for me", but there's no way to delete the App from the App catalog.

I can't update the App as well. When I try to update the app I get a message saying `App already exists`

How can I delete the custom App from Teams?

Comment: Teams => Apps on left navigation => Built For your org=> Select the app => Delete as mention in below image, [![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0yDu.png
 For Update the Custom App refer the following document.
 Ref Doc:-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/upload-custom-apps#update

Comment: I don't get the three dots "settings" button for my custom apps. see https://imgur.com/CeYkCqZ

Comment: You can delete the App from Teams admin center. login with Teams Admin center=>teams app=>manage apps=>select app=>delete
 [![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wugiF.png

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: I can remove the app from the Teams admin center, but it still shows up in the Teams desktop app

Comment: I tried to repro the scenario ,but it's working fine with us. Could you please check it once?