# Unable to delete "old" versions of my app from teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm unable to "Preview in Teams" because I'm getting the error `The webApplicationInfo.Id is already in use by another app installed in the team.`

I believe the root cause is that previous versions of the app are still around. When I go Apps => Manage your apps  I see my app listed twice, and trying to delete them gives the error `There was an issue while trying to remove <app name>. Please try again.`

[Error popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V88bZ.png)[Trying to delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlLcQ.png)

I've tried clearing Teams app cache, deleting re-installing the Teams app, removing the app from like 6 different places (what the heck is "entra" anyways) and I can't get these apps to go away.

I thought this was going to solve my problems: [How to remove/delete/uninstall the app from Teams admin centre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73077914/how-to-remove-delete-uninstall-the-app-from-teams-admin-centre)
but the apps still aren't gone
Same with this: [Why can't I remove my custom App from MS Teams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70730283/why-cant-i-remove-my-custom-app-from-ms-teams)

Comment: After deleting the app from Teams admin centre also, you were able to find the instances in MS Teams apps section?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That did help, now I only have 2 "zombie apps" left (that's what I call them). 
This is now causing a new problem - when trying to send notifications to myself, using something like `client.api('/teams/${this.teamId}/sendActivityNotification').post(sendActivityNotification)` , I receive the following error message 
 `Error: Found multiple applications with the same AAD App ID '...' - a Teams Application ID is required to resolve which application is correct.`

Comment: This error is happening because, its able to get other similar Apps having same Id in Teams. Make sure you have removed the apps from personal scope and channel scopes as well if anywhere you have installed